# Gulp не обрабатывает sass

Tags: gulp, sass, scss

Gulp прекрасно установлен и глобально и локально. В папке с проектом локально установлен sass.

Хочу .scss файл обработать и сохранить в другой папке. При вызове в командной строке все успешно завершается, но папка build так и не появляется.

Если же удаляю строку с вызовом обработки sass - папка появляется, но .scss-файл разумеется копируется в исходном виде.

В чем может быть проблема?

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('publish_css', function() {
gulp.src('css/**/*.scss')
  .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('build/styles'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Код выше рабочий.
Как выяснилось, в самом коде зря хотел явно впилить вложенность папок, оно так не робит
    gulp.src('css/folder/**/*.scss')

Надо просто
    gulp.src('css/**/*.scss')
Особенности семантики, видать.
Вопрос закрыт.